# R index numeric(0) instead of 0

Tags: r, for-loop, indexing

This is the whole thing and it still does not work. I guess the problem is the second Amat condition and the if else structure:

```
Dmat <- matrix(0,nrow= J, ncol=J)
diag(Dmat) <- 1
dvec <- rep(0,J)
dvec <- -hsmooth
Aeq <- matrix(nrow= J, ncol=0)
beq <- rep(0)
Amat <- matrix(0,J,2*J-3)
bvec <- vector(mode="numeric", length=2*J-3)

for(j in 1:J)
{
Amat[j-1,j-1] = -1
Amat[j,j-1]   = 1
bvec[j-1]     = Delta1
}

for(j in 2:J){
Amat[j,J-1+j-2]   = -1/ (Q[j] - Q[j-1])  
if (j==2)
{Amat[j-1,J-1+j-2] = 1/(Q[j] - Q[j-1]) + 1/(Q[j-1] - 0)
}
else
{Amat[j-1,J-1+j-2] = 1/(Q[j] - Q[j-1]) + 1/(Q[j-1] - Q[j-2])
}
Amat[j-2,J-1+j-2] = -1/ (Q[j-1] - Q[j-2])
bvec[J-1+j-2]     = Delta2
}

solution1 <- solve.QP(Dmat, dvec, Amat, bvec, meq=0, factorized=FALSE)
```

The math form is the following:

min sum(mj- m^), where j goes from 1 to J.

st.

mj-1 <= mj - delta1

1/(Qj-1 -Qj-2)(mj-2 -mj-1) <= 1/(Qj -Qj-1 ) (mj-1 - mj) -delta2

I would really appreciate if some help here.

Comment: Do you now that in `R` indexing begins with 1? (`R` is not `C`!)

Comment: ["A special case is the zero index, which has null effects: x\[0\] is an empty vector"](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Indexing-by-vectors)

Comment: @Roland Good shot! Thx for the comment. It seems that just this behaviour is unwanted for OP - so OP has to rethink the logic of indexing in the code.

Comment: What are `Delta1` and `Delta2`? In the first for-loop you have the same problem with the index 0.

Comment: `dvec <- rep(0,J)` is obsolete because you are doing `dvec <- -hsmooth` in the next line. What is `hsmooth` ?

Comment: instead of the first for-loop I would do: `diag(Amat) <- -1;
Amat[cbind(2:J, 1:(J-1))] <- 1;
bvec[1:J] <- Delta1`

Answer (score 1):

`R` is not `C`. Indices in `R` start with `1`, not with zero. So the first element in `Q` ist `Q[1]`. This is unlike a number of other (`C`-inspired) languages but mor like usual math notation.

So you probably want to replace `Q[j-2]` by `Q[j-1]`.

#### Edit:

The question has been changed a lot since I put my answer up. The problem still remains:

```
for(j in 1:J)
{
    Amat[j-1,j-1] = -1
```

Wenn `j` is `1`, then `j-1` is zero and `Amat[0,0]` is not a useful expression, when indices are supposed to start from `1`.

Comment: Just to nitpick: I'm not sure how 1-based indexing is *"more like usual math notation"*.

Comment: Nicking accepted - was not my most brilliant wording ever. What I mean is: If you look at the wikipedia under the topic "Summation", the first notation you will find is $\sum_{i=1}^{100} i$. I am under the impression, that it is more usual, to have `i` start from `1` than from zero (I may be wrong).

Comment: @Bernard Fair enough;-) Most mathematical series that would come to my mind in a first instance start at zero: geometric, Taylor, exponential function, ... (for what it's worth, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series) for many more series starting from either 0 or 1)

Comment: @MauritsEvers Point taken. In any case, it has probably cost lots ans lots of people taken time and effort, that all programming languages are not the same and that pseudocode is -in this respect- either right for most mainstream languages (C++, Java, JS, Python,...) or for `R`.

Comment: @Bernard Agreed. I starting coding in Fortran (1-based indexing) as a student (Physicists love Fortran) and then at some point moved to C/C++ (0-based indexing). The errors I made back then (and subsequent debug sessions) still haunt me;-)